# Windows task scheduler Vs. node cron schedule

Tags: php, node.js, windows, cron, scheduled-tasks

We are working on an application which gonna handle `SMS` sending in schedule , we have `windows server` and we use `Task Scheduler` of windows for this purpose .
Actually I am not okay with this tool that windows provided for us , we use `nodejs` for message sending and `php` for message `queuing` for nodejs. we have `node-cron` and it is really cool for node side , but in `php` side we use windows task scheduler.

we could use node-cron to call `wget` for php and remove windows task scheduler . Is this a good choose ? which one do you prefer ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: *we could use node-cron to call wget for php and remove windows task scheduler* - why? Are they on different machines? You could use Node for scheduling. https://github.com/agenda/agenda is good enough . It uses Mongo for persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `nodejs` could be a good choice,cause you can use [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) for schedule a container execution.
You can also use good features like `Queue` OR `stop/resume` mechanism , and various libraries for scheduling like [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) , [Kue](https://github.com/lykmapipo/kue-scheduler) , [Bee](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) ,[Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda)